# magento remove fields from payment method

Tags: php, magento

I've already integrate my website with a 3-party payment gateway, everything is working perfect, but now, i want to remove some fields from the payment method, i just want to use the credit card type in this step, obviously, i can't just delete the html code from
**app\design\frontend\enterprise\mytheme\template\payment\form\ccsave.phtml**
 cuz i wont work, i already tried with that, and when you click the continue button, nothing really happen, no error message, nothing, so, need some help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your payment model is descended from `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` which has member fields `$_formBlockType` and `$_infoBlockType`.

Override those fields to class aliases for your custom blocks, descendants of `Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Ccsave` and `Mage_Payment_Block_Info_Ccsave` respectively. In those new blocks set the templates to files based on the two **ccsave.phtml** files, but with your field alterations.